# change control pannel icon when am create vs 2010 setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I want to change the control panel icon when I create a setup in vs 2010. Please help me do this.Am not able to create this.

Comment: [Default application icon can change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041291/how-to-change-windows-applicatoins-default-icon-in-setup-project) but what you mean by **control panel icon**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Amulraj,

```
        1.) Go in the properties of setup (Select setup project then press F4). 
        2.)Select Addremoveprogramicons property.
        3.)Browse ico file there.
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: am using vs 2010. 2.)Select Addremoveprogramicons property
not appear in properties.

Comment: I am also using ultimate version.When you press F4 then you will get properties