# Setting a shortcut icon in a setup project

Tags: c#, icons, setup-project, visual-studio-2015

So I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community and I recently downloaded and installed the [VS 2015 Installer Project add-on](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects). Following the instructions from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041291/how-to-change-windows-applicatoins-default-icon-in-setup-project), I attempted to set the icon for the desktop shortcut in the setup project. However, it did not work.

Am I missing a step or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Setup Creation you have to add a Shortcut to the Main Application Output, then u select that Shortcut, go to properties, Icon, change that to the icon you want :)
[image]